# Is there a way to search the Septuagint for a string of words eg. "Τί ἐμοὶ καὶ σοί"?

Tags: greek, word-study

I have tools to search for the lemma, or the exact form.
But sometimes, as in this case, I really need the string of words. Using any one word would bring up too many hits.
Obviously, I need to view every occurrence in LXX.

Comment: Use search in the Blue Letter Bible. Copy and paste the string and choose LXX from the drop down menu. https://www.blueletterbible.org/search/search.cfm?Criteria=%CE%A4%CE%AF+%E1%BC%90%CE%BC%CE%BF%E1%BD%B6+%CE%BA%CE%B1%E1%BD%B6+%CF%83%CE%BF%CE%AF&t=LXX#s=s_primary_0_1

Comment: Whoever down-voted this, without leaving a comment, just earned it an up-vote that I probably wouldn't have given otherwise.

Comment: Thx, RevLad for the link. I've tried BLB before and never worked it out, for some reason. The problem, as I've found before, is it only lists so many hits - not many at all. (Here it omits 2 Kings 3.13. I've not included hits where numbering is not as per MT).

Comment: To add to what @RevelationLad stated, don't just paste τί ἐμοὶ καὶ σοί into the search field by itself. Enclose it within quotation marks, [as such](https://www.blueletterbible.org/search/search.cfm?Criteria=%22%CF%84%E1%BD%B7+%E1%BC%90%CE%BC%CE%BF%E1%BD%B6+%CE%BA%CE%B1%E1%BD%B6+%CF%83%CE%BF%E1%BD%B7%22&t=LXX#s=s_primary_0_1). Being free, BlueLetterBible is one of the most useful Bible sites around, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I get searching the phrase in quotes "Τί ἐμοὶ καὶ σοί" in the LXX using Logos Bible Software.  I expect other software can do this.

Judges 11:12
12 Καὶ ἀπέστειλεν Ιεφθαε ἀγγέλους πρὸς βασιλέα υἱῶν Αμμων λέγων Τί ἐμοὶ καὶ σοί, ὅτι ἥκεις πρός με σὺ πολεμῆσαί με ἐν τῇ γῇ μου;
12 Καὶ ἀπέστειλεν Ιεφθαε ἀγγέλους πρὸς βασιλέα υἱῶν Αμμων λέγων Τί ἐμοὶ καὶ σοί, ὅτι ἦλθες πρός με τοῦ παρατάξασθαι ἐν τῇ γῇ μου;

3 Kingdoms 17:18
18 καὶ εἶπεν πρὸς Ηλιου Τί ἐμοὶ καὶ σοί, ἄνθρωπε τοῦ θεοῦ; εἰσῆλθες πρός με τοῦ ἀναμνῆσαι τὰς ἀδικίας μου καὶ θανατῶσαι τὸν υἱόν μου.

4 Kingdoms 3:13
13 καὶ εἶπεν Ελισαιε πρὸς βασιλέα Ισραηλ Τί ἐμοὶ καὶ σοί; δεῦρο πρὸς τοὺς προφήτας τοῦ πατρός σου. καὶ εἶπεν αὐτῷ ὁ βασιλεὺς Ισραηλ Μή, ὅτι κέκληκεν κύριος τοὺς τρεῖς βασιλεῖς τοῦ παραδοῦναι αὐτοὺς εἰς χεῖρας Μωαβ.

2 Chronicles 35:21
21 καὶ ἀπέστειλεν πρὸς αὐτὸν ἀγγέλους λέγων Τί ἐμοὶ καὶ σοί, βασιλεῦ Ιουδα; οὐκ ἐπὶ σὲ ἥκω σήμερον πόλεμον ποιῆσαι, καὶ ὁ θεὸς εἶπεν κατασπεῦσαί με, πρόσεχε ἀπὸ τοῦ θεοῦ τοῦ μετʼ ἐμοῦ, μὴ καταφθείρῃ σε.

EsdA 1:24
24 καὶ διεπέμψατο βασιλεὺς Αἰγύπτου πρὸς αὐτὸν λέγων Τί ἐμοὶ καὶ σοί ἐστιν, βασιλεῦ τῆς Ιουδαίας;

Septuaginta: With morphology (Jdg 11:12–Esd A 1:24). (1996). Deutsche Bibelgesellschaft.

Comment: Thanks. This appears to be the complete list w/ no false positives. So, although it is not free to use, it helped me evaluate the others.

Answer (score 0):

According to ChatGPT-3.5 the phrase occurs 17 times in the Septuagint:

- Judges (Judges 11:12)
- 2 Kingdoms (2 Samuel 16:10; 2 Samuel 19:22)
- 3 Kingdoms (1 Kings 17:18)
- 4 Kingdoms (2 Kings 3:13; 2 Kings 9:18)
- 1 Chronicles (1 Chronicles 21:3)
- 2 Chronicles (2 Chronicles 35:21)
- Tobit (Tobit 5:17; Tobit 11:2)
- Esther (Esther [Greek version] 15:11)
- Psalms (Psalm 49:16 [Greek numbering]; Psalm 123:3 [Greek numbering])
- Proverbs (Proverbs 6:3)
- Isaiah (Isaiah 7:27; Isaiah 36:11)
- Hosea (Hosea 14:8 [Greek numbering])
- Zechariah (Zechariah 3:7)

Comment: According to ChatGPT, sets of relatively prime numbers define a matroid, known as the [Coprime Matroid](https://chat.openai.com/chat/dc92867a-87a3-4339-a4b3-1b84755da230). The proof is mostly correct, but wrong ({{6},{2,3}) is a counter example), and I'm really impressed that it would create such an amazingly appropriate name for this thing that no one has ever heard of before. ¶ ChatGPT provides answers that sound as close as possible to what you seem to want. It will of course make up facts when it needs to (much like many postings on many sites from real people).

Comment: I don't see ChatGPT any differently than Logos as a verse search tool.  In the end, both are just doing pattern matching.  It's also a lot cheaper than Logos.

Comment: ChatGPT is impressive, but it is unreliable, and it really does make things up and give wrong answers.

Comment: Which of the above answers were incorrect?

Comment: I'm not saying they *are* incorrect; I'm saying ChatGPT is a demonstrably unreliable source, known for making things up in order to provide a satisfying answer. ¶ I noticed a similar scene in a movie "The Ruling Class" and a TV show "The Prisoner", and asked if they had any cast or crew in common. It told me that the common link was Patrick McGoohan. who also had a part in the movie. That was an ideal answer, more than expected, as there couldn't have been a better person to be the link. Except It lied about it. Patrick McGoohan didn't play the character. I pointed this out, and it apologized.

Answer (score 0):

One can search Ellopos for such a question.  Here is the result that it gave for this:

https://www.ellopos.net/search/septuagint-search.asp?cx=partner-pub-9189756092389553%3A3577570990&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&q=%CE%A4%CE%AF+%E1%BC%90%CE%BC%CE%BF%E1%BD%B6+%CE%BA%CE%B1%E1%BD%B6+%CF%83%CE%BF%CE%AF&sa=Search&siteurl=www.ellopos.net%2Fsearch%2Fseptuagint-search.asp&ref=www.ellopos.net%2Felpenor%2Fgreek-texts%2Fseptuagint%2F&ss=157j24649j2

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: That gets a lot of false hits.  E.g. "**σοί**. 8 δεῖξον ἡμῖν, Κύριε, τὸ ἔλεός σου **καὶ** τὸ σωτήριόν σου δῴης ἡμῖν. 9 ἀκούσομαι **τί** λαλήσει ἐν **ἐμοὶ**" Κύριος  in Psalms 84. The BLB is much better (it shows exact matches separately), but that answer was posted as a comment.

Comment: Thanks. lots of false positives - and really clunky to use.